# Showing set in subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is not open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How do you show that there is no open set $U$ in  $\mathbb{R}$ such that $U\cap [2,4] = [3,4] $?

I can see why it can’t be true if $U$ is an open interval since the intersection won’t have $3$ as an endpoint. But for a general open set I’m stuck and not sure what argument I’m missing.

Comment: It will contain $4+\frac 1 n$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: Hint: there *is* an open set $V$ in $\Bbb{R}$ such that $V \cap [2, 4] = (3, 4]$. What's the difference here?

Comment: In this case we cant put U=[3,4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $3\in U\cap [2,4]$, we conclude that $3\in U$. Since $U$ is open, it contains a small interval around $3$ - $I=(3-\epsilon,3+\epsilon)\subset U$. But for $\epsilon$ small enough, $I\subset [2,4]$ as well, so $I\subset U\cap [2,4]=[3,4]$. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is an open set $U=(a,b)$ such that $(a,b) \cap [2,4]=[3,4]$.  So $3$, and $4$ belongs to $U'$. Now, if $a=3$ then it must be that $U=[3,4)$ which is not open. And if $a \not =3)$ then the $(a,b) \cap [2,4]\not=[3,4]$. So there is no such open set.